# Can we no longer export static pages in nextjs 14?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm trying to export my project to static HTML pages and I don't get the CSS styles

My configuration in next.config.js

```
** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  images: {
    unoptimized: true,
  },
  output: "export",
  reactStrictMode: false,
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

and when I try to run npm run build I find that the files do appear in the output folder but when I put them on a web server the CSS styles are not there

Try making a new example by running

```
npx create-next-app@lates
```

in next.config.js I put
`output: "export",`
and execute

```
npm run build
```

and the CSS is not exported either

Maybe nextjs no longer allows you to export static pages?

In the console I don't get any errors, only the files are without styles and probably also without JavaScript

Comment: @ruakh Please see the FAQ [How do I deal with non-English content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297673/215552) From the answer: "Non-English questions should not be translated into English by anyone other than the original poster (OP)."

Comment: @HereticMonkey: Thanks for the note! I'm aware of that policy, but this *isn't* a "Non-English question". Since the question itself was already in English, I decided it made most sense to update the title to match. (I'm guessing that the OP was originally going to write the question in Spanish, then realized that Stack Overflow requires English, but forgot to go back and update the title accordingly.)

Comment: that's how it was, my apologies

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  distDir: "build",
  output: "export",
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Ensure that your CSS files are being imported correctly in your components/pages. Verify that the import paths are correct, and the CSS files are present in the expected locations.

Worked for me.

css location should be there

yourApp\build_next\static\css

Here you can find more.

https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/deploying/static-exports

Hope It will work.
I am new to this too. Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, with the configuration of next Config it made me a folder called build and when I ran the npm run build command it made the files good for me but the result is the same it still does not have css styles when I move it to my hosting